# What is the best way to embed a part of one page in another in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig

In my project I often need to reuse the same template on different pages usually with the different filter parameters. I considered to use controller methods and the twig `render` function to carry it out.

In my controller:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    return $this->render("index.html.twig");
}
public function list(Request $request, array $filterArray = []) {
    return $this->render("list.html.twig", [
        'items' => $this->getFilteredItems($filterArray)
    ]);
}
public function entry(Request $request, string $alias) {
    return $this->render("entry.html.twig"[
        'item' => $this->getItemByAlias($alias)
    ]);
}
```

In `index.html.twig`:

```
{{ render(controller(
    'App\\Controller\\SynthesisController::entityList', {},
    {  }
)) }}
```

In `list.html.twig`:

```
{% for item in items %}
<div class="">
    <a href="">{{item.name}}</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

And so it allows me to reuse the list of entities in other pages with its layout. In `entry.html.twig`:

```
<div class="synthesis-participants">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-4">
            <div class="h5">Reagents:</div>

            {{ render(controller(
                'App\\Controller\\SubstanceController::entityList', { 'filterArray': {
                    'participate': { 'synthesis': item.id, 'role': 10 }
                } }, { }
            )) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-4">
            <div class="h5">Products:</div>

            {{ render(controller(
                'App\\Controller\\SubstanceController::entityList', { 'filterArray': {
                    'participate': { 'synthesis': item.id, 'role': 20 }
                } }, { }
            )) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-4">
            <div class="h5">Diluents:</div>

            {{ render(controller(
                'App\\Controller\\SubstanceController::entityList', { 'filterArray': {
                    'participate': { 'synthesis': item.id, 'role': 30 }
                } }, { }
            )) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-4">
            <div class="h5">Catalysts:</div>

            {{ render(controller(
                'App\\Controller\\SubstanceController::entityList', { 'filterArray': {
                    'participate': { 'synthesis': item.id, 'role': 40 }
                } }, { }
            )) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="mt-2">{{ item.text }}</p>
</div>
```

May be it can be reached in a better way?

Comment: This is the best way there is at the moment. You always have to call a method with arguments. If you don't want to render a template, you might use Twig filter/function. But with your setup, I think you have the best option there is at the moment.

Comment: You could reduce some code still by using a loop e.g. `{% for title, role in { 'foo': 10, 'bar': 20, 'foobar': 30, } %}...{% endfor %}`

Comment: Take a look at the SonataBlockBundle https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataBlockBundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should avoid this way since you are embedding too many controllers and I find the overhead bigger than the benefit.

Alternatively you could add some functionality in each of your controllers to get the necessary information and then include the appropriate templates in your twig.

I would change your controllers to something like this:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    return $this->render("index.html.twig", [
        'items' => $this->getFilteredItems()
    ]);
}

public function list(Request $request, array $filterArray = []) {
    return $this->render("list.html.twig", [
        'items' => $this->getFilteredItems($filterArray)
    ]);
}

public function entry(Request $request, string $alias) {
    $item = $this->getItemByAlias($alias);
    $items = [];
    $titles = ['Reagents', 'Products', 'Diluents', 'Catalysts']; 
    foreach (range(10, 40, 10) as $key => $role) {
        $filter['participate'] = [
            'synthesis' => $item['id'], // $item->getId()
            'role' => $role
        ];
        $title = $titles[$key];
        $items[$title] = $this->getFilteredItems($filter);
    }

    return $this->render("entry.html.twig"[
        'item' => $this->getItemByAlias($alias),
        'items' => $items
    ]);
}
```

Finally, in your `entry.html.twig`:

```
<div class="synthesis-participants">
    {% for key, itemArray in items %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 mb-4">
            <div class="h5">{{ key }} :</div>
            {% include 'list.html.twig' with {'items': itemArray} only %} 
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <p class="mt-2">{{ item.text }}</p>
</div>
```

I would also suggest that the functions `getItemByAlias`, `getFilteredItems` shouldn't live in the controller but in a repository or service.